# Browse and merger Excel files in a folder and its subfolders in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a folder which contains multiple subfolders, I want to browser all excel files end with xlsx and merger them into one single xlsx file with following code:

```
import os
import glob

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/Test"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             #print(os.path.join(root, file))
             s = os.path.join(root, file)
             print(s)
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in s:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)

# now save the data frame
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx')
all_data.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

While an error happens when it run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-169-41c6d76207e7>", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(f)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D'
```

Does someone know how to deal with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: your problem is with `df = pd.read_excel(f)`. so what is the contents of `f`? it looks like python thinks that it's `'D'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with `df = pd.read_excel(f)`. What are the contents of `f`? It looks like Python thinks that it's 'D'.

This is because your `for f in s:` is just iterating over the string that you created with `s = os.path.join(root, file)`. I think you want to be saving this in some container like so

```
paths = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/Test"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
             #print(os.path.join(root, file))
             s = os.path.join(root, file)
             print(s)
             paths.append(s)

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in paths:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

You can also reduce that initial `for` loop into a list comprehension with

```
paths = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, _, files in os.walk('D:/Test') for file in files if file.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

Comment: by the way, what i should modify to get the paths of Word files end with doc or docx?

Comment: @ahbon, do you mean Excel files? you could go `if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

listof_files = os.listdir()
current_file_name = os.path.basename(__file__)

#flag to make sure append is happening properly
count = 0
mainFrame = 0

for file in listof_files:
    #To ignore the python script file for pd.read_excel
    if((file != current_file_name) and (file.endswith(".xlsx"))):

        tempdf = pd.read_excel(str(file))

        if(count == 0): 
            mainFrame = tempdf.copy()
        else: 
            mainFrame = pd.concat([mainFrame,tempdf])

        count += 1

mainFrame.to_excel('final.xlsx',index=False)
```

You can do like this also, put the script in the folder where you have all the xlsx files, then run the script, it will fetch all the xlsx file and concat with each other, finally, a single excel file is formed.

Comment: File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 636, in biff2_8_load
    raise XLRDError("Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document")

XLRDError: Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document

Comment: thanks for your help. but it generates another error above.